# Delete Columns within a Pandas Dataframe column range where sum of each column is less than 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, calculated-columns

I need to iterate over a predefined range of columns and delete/drop a column if the total row sum value of that column is less than 10 but I can't get it to work. So far I have tried the following with various iteration:

```
for column in FinalData.columns[109:]:
    if FinalData[column].sum < 10:
        FinalData[column].drop
```

The dataframe FinalData holds 300 columns of data, I want to apply to columns 109 onwards only.
 Running the code above generates the error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'int'
```

I'm pretty new to Python and using it just for data analysis, any help would be welcome.

Comment: Could you add some example data of how your actual data looks like, because the line _"delete/drop a column if the total row sum value of that column is less than 10"_ is a bit contradicting. Since you can get total of a column, or the total of a row of multiple columns.

Comment: `sum()` not `sum`, and `drop()` not `drop`.  These are properties, not methods, you need to call them.

Comment: Erfan. I want to get a total for a column at a time and delete that column if it meets the criteria. So if I have 10k rows and 100 columns,  I want to calculate the sum of all of those 10k cells in column 1 (in isolation with no relation to any other column in the DF), if that sum is less than 10, then I want to remove that column to delete that column otherwise and then evaluate the next column.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because one of the columns contains non-numeric data. If you want the code to run without errors (i.e. only drop numeric columns with sum >10), you can use:

```
from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

for column in FinalData.columns[109:]:
    if is_numeric_dtype(FinalData[column]):
        if sum(FinalData[column]) < 10:
           FinalData.drop([column], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: `sum` is a method, not a property.  You need to call it, or you will get the same error.  He is comparing the method to an integer, not the result of calling the method, his error shows nothing to do with non-numeric data

Comment: Thanks Carsten for the code. I tried running but can confirm User348203 is right, it still wont run. So how do I call a function? Do I need to write def function similar to a UDF in VBA?

Comment: You cannot call the sum function by writing `.sum`. However, my code above uses ´sum()´ which is a function. Alternatively you can try `np.sum()`.

Comment: Oh sorry Carsten. Didn't realise you'd fixed that element. I tried running it but am getting TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable. In case extra info would be useful - note the columns I am trying to delete all have either a combination of 1 and 0s in them. And the dtype of these columns is 'uint8'.